# Describe the Calculus Identity $f(x) = f(a-x)$

Tags: calculus, self-learning

To me this reads: "A constant minus x is equivalent to x on $[-\infty, \infty]$".

Comment: Can you give a name for this when $a=0?$

Comment: That would be an even function correct?

Comment: good. What value of $a$ would work with $f(x)=x^2 - 2x +1?$

Comment: $f(1-x)=x^2-2x+1$

Comment: Actually, no, $f(2-x) = f(x),$ because $$ (2-x)^2 -2(2-x) + 1 = 4 - 4x +x^2 -4 +2x+1 = x^2-2x+1.  $$ Note that $$  f(1-x) = (1-x)^2 - 2(1-x)+1 = 1 -2x+x^2 -2 +2x +1 = x^2.$$

Comment: Where was I... If you draw, carefully, a graph of $y=x^2-2x+1,$ you will see that it is symmetric across the vertical line $x=1,$ which is what Marty Cohen's answer predicts.

Comment: This can only hold on $[-\infty,\infty]$ correct? Otherwise the functions would be exactly $a$ different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f is symmetric around a/2.

In other words,
f(a/2+z)
= f(a-(a/2+z))
= f(a/2-z).

Comment: Right so on an infinite bound we expect the shift to become essentially zero and thus the functions are equivalent?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this,particularly "infinite bound". The equation describes a property of the function: the values for x > a/2 determine those for x < a/2 (and vice versa). I don't see how "shift" applies.

Comment: I follow what you have written, but it does not explain how $f(z) = f(\frac{a}{2}+z)$

Comment: I wrote f(a/2+z) = f(a/2-z) and I meant it.